# AngularJS select default value with ng-model and ng-repeat instead ng-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<select ng-model="model.RemediationCredentials" name="remediationCredential" id="remediationCredential">
    <option value="0">---</option>
    <option ng:repeat="cred in credentialsList" 
                 data-index="{{$index}}" value="{{cred.Value}}">{{cred.Key}}</option>
</select>
```

and `credentialsList` looks like:

```
credentialsList = [  { Key: "Panda", Value: "Zoo: } ]
```

I think I need to use `ng-repeat` vs `ng-option` to do some basic things like the no selection and do the `data-index`.  However, when I try to set the model it doesn't work...

```
$scope.model.RemediationCredentials = "Zoo"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need the index attached to the element itself? Would obtaining the index upon selection change suffice?

Answer (score 4):

use the Angular Select Directive:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Should look something more like this:

```
<select ng-model="model.RemediationCredentials" name="remediationCredential" id="remediationCredential" ng-options="cred.value as cred.key for cred in credentialsList">
    <option value="0">---</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What about the data-index portion?

Comment: what do you need the index for? you could always do a lookup in the controller on the original object to get the index.

Comment: @amcdnl make the `value=""` to keep your null option available once the model renders.

Comment: don't worry about the value attribute in the options that get generated, that is not the actual value that gets returned. Angular will bind the selected value to the model provided to the select.